# python importing mysql.connector can crash (seg fault) if done in particular order

Tags: python, python-requests, python-imaging-library, mysql-python

I am using python 3.7.9 and mysql-connector-python 8.0.22 on debian using virtualenv and all modules installed with pip3.
I encountered a strange issue where importing this together with other modules, if I do this in certain order, it will crash with "Segmentation fault".

Crashed:

```
import requests
import mysql.connector

import PIL
from PIL import Image
```

Ok:

```
import requests

import PIL
from PIL import Image

import mysql.connector
```

Simply reordering like above will make this problem disappeared. I am not sure it has to do with some libs used by all modules involved and the orderings that will make it work seems to change if i import other modules... so far, I can't find any patterns.

I am new at debugging python at dynamic library loading level, if you experience this same problem, please share if you know how to fix this.

Comment: I have this problem on `Linux Mint 20` with `Python 3.7.9` and `PIL 7.0.0` but not with `Python 3.8.5` and `PIL 8.0.`. And after updating to `PIL 8.10` it works also on `Python 3.7.9`

Comment: @metatoaster Everything I did here is already in a venv and pip.

Comment: @furas I was under the impression the issue is caused by mysql connector, but for you, it seems to be PIL? i think more debugging needed to properly characterize the issue. I still think it is caused by conflict involving dynamic libraries and interdependencies.

Comment: @furas Mine is also Pillow 8.1.0 (if that's what you have).

Comment: it works for me with `python3.8`, `requests: 2.25.1`, `MySQL: 2.2.9`, `PIL: 8.0.1` and with `python3.7`, `requests: 2.25.1`, `MySQL: 2.2.9`, `PIL: 8.1.0`